# Can I create .pkpass dynamically from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, passbook

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852077/can-we-create-a-pass-pkpass-file-programatically-in-xcode) answer on stackoverflow which says it is possible to create .pkpass from iOS app but I really didn't find any code or anything to create that.

I also checked on Apple developers page about Passbook and Passes. I know how to create static `.pkpass` by using `bundle` using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1) link.

But what I want to do is dynamically create passes from my iOS app. Each passes will have different contents.

I searched everywhere online. Most of the answers are in favor of creating `web-server` for generating `.pkpass`

Any guidance will be appreciated. I am fairly new to iOS development so I might not know obvious things.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but due to the fact that the pass needs to be cryptographically signed, and that Apple documentations states this should be done on a server, you may have trouble getting such an app into the app store. The standard approach is to build an API (or use a third party service) to create the passes on demand and download them onto the device.